# Open/Display Angular 5 route in Material 2 Dialog component

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material2

I have a path in my `app-routing.module.ts` that accept project ID and display project's details

```
{
path: 'project-details/:projectId',
component: ProjectDetailsComponent,
}
```

I have another path which is my app's homepage, where I display a carousel of projects

```
{
path: 'home',
component: HomeComponent
}
```

In my carousel which is placed in `home.component.html` file I have action button for each carousel item which for now redirects to the above `project-details` path, passing the project's ID to the `click()` method on the button.

What I'm looking for is to display the project details page as it is in a MatDialog component (I'm using Angular Material 2).

What confuses me, is that I started out creating:-

1- Component `ProjectDetailsModalComponent`

2- and in my `openProject()` method I did call `this.dialog.open(ProjectDetailsModalComponent)`

3- Then I realized that I will need to implement the same logic and template I have in `ProjectDetailsComponent` into `ProjectDetailsModalComponent`

As far as I know the MatDialog Component in Angular Material 2 library do not offer such approach, you define the dialog logic and template. Knowing that `router-outlet` wont help that much as the template I want to display is already existing and it's not a child of home path and it will also display in a separate template file (dialog template) not in `home.component.html`